# export from outlook.com external users using powershell

Tags: powershell

Does anyone know how to export data from the external contacts in live@edu, using PowerShell? I need all name fields (first name, last name etc). I have been able to do it using:

```
Get-MailContact -ResultSize Unlimited | Where {($_.WhenCreated -gt (get-date).adddays(-300))} | Export-Csv d:\external
```

But this gives me a lot of data I dont need and only the full name and not the name fields seperatly.

I can also use:

```
Get-MailContact -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,EmailAddresses,MailboxPlan,ServerName,DatabaseName | Export-Csv .\output.csv
```

Which doesnt give me the FirstName, LastName either. Even if I add it to the list (in which case it results in 2 blank columns with just the titles.

Comment: Are you sure the name "outlook.com" is correct? (I have no idea what that is, and as your question is not tagged Outlook either, I'm wondering if this is about the Microsoft Outlook email client? Of course, one cannot know everything, but that name "outlook.com" just doesn't seem right.)

Comment: @Arjan: No, it's correct, just not well named. It's Microsoft Outlook Live.

Comment: The documentation says nothing about `FirstName` or `LastName` being returned in the `MailContact` record: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124717.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late, but for those who come across this post, the answer to the original question is to use the `get-recipient` function, e.g.:

```
get-recipient -identity "External Mail Contact 1" | select *    
get-recipient | select DisplayName, FirstName, LastName
```

To get the complete contact details for an external mailbox, e.g. Street Name, Province, Office, Company etc. (this also includes first name, last name, initials etc) use tje `get-contact` function:

```
get-contact -identity "External Mail Contact 1" | select *
get-recipient | select DisplayName, FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, City,
StateOrProvince, Office, Compane, Department
```

Answer (score 0):

Some powershell-fu for exchange is discussed here: http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aff/3/aft/2405/afv/topic/Default.aspx

I see them using the current record name property, claiming to return first and last name comma separated...I think your problem is just figuring out the property names for what you want to do.

Comment: I think you need to be a part of or inside of a corporate organization to use that tool it is looking for a domain controller to query. Which is not exactly usable in this situation since Sharron is trying to use it against live@edu.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading an installed email client and connecting it to your live@edu account at outlook.com. One that I would suggest that you use that is free is [Windows Live Mail 2011](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mail?os=other). Once you have synced your account locally on your computer follow the instructions [here](http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/windowsLiveMail/addressBooksAndContacts/exportContacts.htm) to export your contacts to a csv file which is viewable in excel or notepad if your desperate.